# $slice implemented in the php driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, push, slice

My question is if one can use '$slice' with the update() and $push in mongodb.

I already tried this: (with and without casting to (object)

```
$db->collection->update(
     array('_id' => new MongoId($id)), 

     (object)array( '$push' => 
          array('thumbs' => array(
               '$each' => $items, 
               '$slice' => -5
))));
```

But the only thing that happens is mongo adding the whole second array in update() to the collection. So I get

```
thumbs: [ { "$each" : ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you casting the update param as an Object?

Comment: Because php can't distinguish between objects and arrays in the collection. [] = object and {} = array. But even if I don't cast it, it does not work.

Comment: That doesn't matter with the PHP driver, dicts and arrays are analogous (as you stated) and the PHP driver can encode to the correct notation regardless. What MongoDB version are you on? The `$slice` operator is very new (v2.4.3) so it seems that this is what is happening, MongoDB is reading this as a normal document because it doesn't understand the operators you have put in

Answer (score 0):

You are running MongoDB pre 2.4.

MongoDB 2.4 introduced the [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/slice/), and previous the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/) operator did not support the [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/each/) operator.

When MongoDB encounters an unrecognised operators like this (i.e. in MongoDB 2.2) for $push it will believe it is actually the keys you want to use and treat it like any other data.